# Make contour of scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, scatter-plot

In python, If I have a set of data

```
x, y, z
```

I can make a scatter with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x,y,c=z)
```

How I can get a `plt.contourf(x,y,z)` of the scatter ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [tricontourf](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf) as suggested in case **b.** of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407498/4124317):

```
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.tricontour(x, y, z, 15, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
plt.tricontourf(x, y, z, 15)
```

### **Old reply:**

Use the following function to convert to the format required by contourf:

```
from numpy import linspace, meshgrid
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

def grid(x, y, z, resX=100, resY=100):
    "Convert 3 column data to matplotlib grid"
    xi = linspace(min(x), max(x), resX)
    yi = linspace(min(y), max(y), resY)
    Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
    X, Y = meshgrid(xi, yi)
    return X, Y, Z
```

Now you can do:

```
X, Y, Z = grid(x, y, z)
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
```

[image]

Comment: you import griddata from ? ... `from scipy.interpolate import griddata` or `from matplotlib.mlab import griddata`

Comment: @JuanPablo, ups, you are right, fixed(`from matplotlib.mlab import griddata` is the right one).

Comment: `from matplotlib.mlab import griddata` is deprecated as of matplotlib 2.2

Comment: `Deprecated since version 2.2: The griddata function was deprecated in Matplotlib 2.2 and will be removed in 3.1. Use scipy.interpolate.griddata instead.`

Comment: Here `plt.tricontourf(x, y, z, 15)`, what does the `15` means?

Answer (score 16):

The solution will depend on how the data is organized.

## Data on regular grid

If the `x` and `y` data already define a grid, they can be easily reshaped to a quadrilateral grid. E.g.

```
#x  y  z
 4  1  3
 6  1  8
 8  1 -9
 4  2 10
 6  2 -1
 8  2 -8
 4  3  8
 6  3 -9
 8  3  0
 4  4 -1
 6  4 -8
 8  4  8
```

can plotted as a [`contour`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour.html) using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x,y,z = np.loadtxt("data.txt", unpack=True)
plt.contour(x.reshape(4,3), y.reshape(4,3), z.reshape(4,3))
```

## Arbitrary data

#### a. Interpolation

In case the data is not living on a quadrilateral grid, one can interpolate the data on a grid. One way to do so is  [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

xi = np.linspace(4, 8, 10)
yi = np.linspace(1, 4, 10)
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear')
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi)
```

#### b. Non-gridded contour

Finally, one can plot a contour completely without the use of a quadrilateral grid. This can be done using [`tricontour`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tricontour.html).

```
plt.tricontour(x,y,z)
```

An example comparing the latter two methods is found on the [matplotlib page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html).

Answer (score 6):

`contour` expects regularly gridded data. You thus need to interpolate your data first:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma
from numpy.random import uniform, seed
# make up some randomly distributed data
seed(1234)
npts = 200
x = uniform(-2,2,npts)
y = uniform(-2,2,npts)
z = x*np.exp(-x**2-y**2)
# define grid.
xi = np.linspace(-2.1,2.1,100)
yi = np.linspace(-2.1,2.1,100)
# grid the data.
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
# contour the gridded data, plotting dots at the randomly spaced data points.
CS = plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,15,linewidths=0.5,colors='k')
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar() # draw colorbar
# plot data points.
plt.scatter(x,y,marker='o',c='b',s=5)
plt.xlim(-2,2)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.title('griddata test (%d points)' % npts)
plt.show()
```

Note that I shamelessly stole this code from the excellent [matplotlib cookbook](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data)

Comment: when I use gridata of `scipy.interpolate`, the program are running a long time, this never stop.

Comment: That of course depends on your data, which you didn't specify in your initial post. You should definitely try playing with the `method` argument of `griddata`. Try `method="nearest"`, which should give the fastest interpolation.