# Error while plotting contour in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have `X coordinates` ,`Y coordinates` and `Zcoordinates`, each  stored in an array with `n x 1  . (n rows,1 column)` .The contour plot in `Matplotlib` allows to plot only if `"*X and Y must both be 2-D with the same shape as Z, or they must both be 1-D such that len(X) is the number of columns in Z and len(Y) is the number of rows in Z.*"`

How can I solve this issue?
 Also the corresponding x,y,z values should be accessible.
 Mixing of data points will cause error in my plot.

Comment: How would you expect the contourplot to look like with 1D z-coordinates(assuming z is what you plot on the x-y plane)? Are you sure you are not looking for a scatterplot or 3d-line plot?

Comment: You could improve this question by providing a minimum working example of the code, which reproduces the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

The way I know is to evaluate z over a grid, composed of x and y:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.plot(X, Y, z)
z = <evaluate over X, Y>
plt.contour(X, Y, z)
plt.show()
```

[This](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) explains it a bit better

Comment: you are assuming that z is defined as a function that can be evaluated on the new grid. It might be a list of spot height measurements of a mountain, so this approach wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Contour expects gridded data. This matplotlib tutorial explains it perfectly:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/griddata_demo.html.
Also see [Make contour of scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764814/make-contour-of-scatter).

Comment: Although quite unlikely in this case, it is a good habit to *Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.* [answer guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks - will keep that in mind :) 
For this particular one, as you've already pointed out, it would be unlikely here as the sites are stackoverflow itself and matplotlib.