# Scatter plot with contour according to a paramter using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, contour

I have a data file having data as shown below:

```
#x       f(x)    g(x)
0.12    -0.43    0.53
0.64     1.34    0.83
and so on...
```

Now, I want to make scatter plot `f(x)` vs `g(x)` and put contour lines on it according to the `x` value of the points in the interval of 0.24. I tried to do the plots using `contour` function but that requires to create a meshgrid and a 2D array and all. But here, `x`, `f(x)` and `g(x)` are all random numbers so I can't create a meshgrid. I need some ideas for how to do this plotting. In addition to that, I have very large datafile (approx. 1.5 GB) and it is taking more than an hour to make a single scatter plot using

```
plt.plot(x,y,'.')
```

Any idea for faster plotting is also appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make contour of scatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764814/make-contour-of-scatter)

Comment: For large data, it is often faster to plot the *density* of points using e.g. `hexbin` or `hist2d`.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't make sense to plot 10 to 60 times more points that your screen has pixels.