# Plotting Windrose: making a pollution rose with concentration set to color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Trying to plot a windrose diagram with speed and direction being plotted and the concentration determining the color. Unfortunately, matplotlib only supports two variables. Can make a nice scatter that shows what I want but not sure how to bin it so that it comes out like the image attached (Halliday et al 2016).

Scatter plot that should be turned into windrose. Areas of high concentration marked by color

[image]

image from paper that I would like to recreate

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The plots shown can be created using a `pcolormesh`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
r = np.linspace(2,15,16)

Theta, R = np.meshgrid(theta, r)
C = np.sinc(Theta-2)+(5-np.sqrt(R))+np.random.rand(len(r),len(theta))
C = np.ma.masked_less_equal(C,2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection":"polar"})

ax.pcolormesh(Theta, R, C, vmin=2, vmax=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do you read in data into this? I'm trying to read in three separate datasets (wind speed, wind direction, and concentration) but it keeps giving a Value Error (not enough to unpack). All three arrays are (1341,). Your code works with the random filler data but not when I try and read my data in

Comment: Your data needs to be 2D arrays, just as in the example. Since I don't know your data, you need to figure that out yourself. You may look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44355400/4124317) for possible ways to obtain 2D data.

Comment: Where should I read in the data? So if var1, var2, and var3 are wind speed, wind direction, and concentration of pollutant, respectively, how would I plot those into your function above? Let's say that all three are 2d arrays. I think I'm getting caught up trying to read the data into the wrong spot.

Comment: If all three input arrays are already 2D arrays of the same shape, `var1` would correspond to `R`, `var2` to `Theta` and `var3` to `C` in the above code. Mind that Theta and R need to form a grid and that `var2` must be in radiants.

Answer (score 0):

As the last answer we can do it with pcolormesh by this way:

Assume that you have the data in this three numpy arrays:

Data of Wind Speed: wspeed_array

Data of Wind Direction: wdir_array

Data of PM or another variable: pm_array

Code here

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

##Variables to custom the graph
ftheta=50 #this is the number of subdivisions of angles in the graph
fr=16 #this is the number of subdivision of concentric circles in the graph
mapa='plasma' #Here you can choose the colormap you prefer
nlevel=15 #This is the subdivisions of color and it depens of the values of pm array

##First we rename the data to name for polar coordinates
#If you have Wind direction with Degrees use this, but if you have in radians use data_theta=wdir_array
#I named it as theta because this angle will give us the direcion on polar coordinates
data_theta = np.radians(wdir_array)
#I named ir r because the wind speed will be the radius of the polar coordinates graph
data_r = wspeed_array
#I used pm name because this is for pollution
data_pm=pm_array

##This part is only necesary if you have ane data Null/Nan, because this graph can't have that data
#I iterate to find the position with NAN, I assumed that we have data point to point with all arrays
eliminar=[]
for i in range(len(data_pm)):
    if np.isnan(data_pm[i]) or np.isnan(data_r[i]) or np.isnan(data_theta[i]):
        eliminar.append(i)
data_pm=np.delete(data_pm,eliminar)
data_r=np.delete(data_r,eliminar)
data_theta=np.delete(data_theta,eliminar)

##Now I generate the subdivisions of the graph (the mesh)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,ftheta)
r = np.linspace(min(data_r),max(data_r),fr)

##Now I generate the mesh, that is a MxN matrix where i have coordinates of each point
Theta, R = np.meshgrid(theta, r)

##Here I generate a circle around each point to take each point and assign it to each coordinate
dr=(r[1]-r[0])/2
dtheta=(theta[1]-theta[0])/2

##This is my matrix where I will put the pm data in each coordinate
C_pm=R*0

#####In this case by each coordinate point I will take every point that exist inside the limits dr and dtheta, then I will calculate the mean
#####of that data and that will be my value of that point. You alsa can use min or max or another function
##I will iterate in each point of the matrix
for i in range(len(Theta)):
    for j in range(len(Theta[0])):
        ##Number of elements to calculate the mean
        cantidad=0
        ##Sum of the values to calculate the mean
        suma=0
        ##I am inside the point and I iterate in the data
        for dato in range(len(data_pm)):
            if data_r[dato]<=(R[i][j]+dr) and data_r[dato]>(R[i][j]-dr) and data_theta[dato]<=(Theta[i][j]+dtheta) and data_theta[dato]>(Theta[i][j]-dtheta):
                suma=suma+data_pm[dato]
                cantidad=cantidad+1
        ## I can't divide by cero so I calculate the mean only if I can
        if cantidad!=0:
            promedio=suma/cantidad
        else:
            promedio=0
        ##I add the result to the point
        C_pm[i][j]=promedio

#I generate the levels of the colors of the pm data
levels = MaxNLocator(nbins=nlevel).tick_values(C_pm.min(), C_pm.max())
#I choose the colormap
cmap = plt.get_cmap(mapa)
#I add the levels and colormap to the bound of each color to each pm level
norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)

#I don't consider the 0 values (remember that I started the C_pm matrix in 0), this will omit the 0 values and all values under 0.05
C_pm = np.ma.masked_less_equal(C_pm,0.05)

#I create the plot as polar
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection":"polar"})

#I add the data to the graph (Matrix of angle values, matrix of radius values (spped) and Matrix of data)
im=ax.pcolormesh(Theta, R, C_pm)
#I add the colorbar to have the value of each color
cbar=fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
#To add title
ax.set_title('TITLE')
#The wind rose is in opposite direction
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
#I set the 90 degrees in the right
ax.set_theta_offset(np.radians(90))
#Only use this if you want to have this labels, if you want degrees omit it
ax.set_xticklabels(['N', 'NW',  'W', 'SW', 'S', 'SE','E', 'NE'])
#Label of the colorbar
cbar.set_label('PM10 ug/m2')
#Show the graph
plt.show()
```

Here you have two graph, one of them in degrees and the another with labels of N, S, W and E

[With degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj3kU.jpg)

[With labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWvBX.jpg)