# Pollution rose plot gridded

Tags: matplotlib, mesh

I am trying to create a pollution rose plot as described in the link [Plotting Windrose: making a pollution rose with concentration set to color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423694/plotting-windrose-making-a-pollution-rose-with-concentration-set-to-color)

Example in the reply is working but when I used my data then it is giving a weird plot. Any advice where I am going wrong? Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

wd = [90.,297.,309.,336.,20.,2.,334.,327.,117.,125.,122.,97.,95.,97.,103.,106.,125.,148.,147.,140.,141.,145.,144.,151.,161.]
ws = [15,1.6,1.8,1.7,2.1,1.6,2.1,1.4,3,6.5,7.1,8.2,10.2,10.2,10.8,10.2,11.4,9.7,8.6,7.1,6.4,5.5,5,5,6]
oz = [10.,20.,30.,40.,50.,60.,70.,80.,90.,100.,110.,120.,90.,140.,100.,106.,125.,148.,147.,140.,141.,145.,144.,151.,161.]

pi_fac = 22/(7*180.)
wd_rad = [w * pi_fac for w in wd]
ws_r = np.linspace(min(ws),max(ws),16)

WD,WS = np.meshgrid(wd_rad,ws_r) 
C = oz + np.zeros((len(ws_r),len(wd)),dtype=float)
C = np.ma.masked_less_equal(C,10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection":"polar"})
ax.pcolormesh(WD,WS,C,vmin=10, vmax=170) # I tried different vmin and vmax too

plt.show()
```

[image: Pic with error]

Comment: Could you paste the code that is working and include a picture of the weird plot you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

The linked post assumes you have a regular grid for directions and for speeds, but your input seems to be quite unordered combinations.

To create a plot with colored regions depending on the `oz` values, you could try `tricontourf`. `tricontourf` takes in X, Y and Z values that don't need to lie on a grid and creates a contour plot. Although it is meant for rectangular layouts, it might also work for your case. It will have a discontinuity though, when crossing from 360º to 0º.

The plot of this example also draws a colorbar to show which range of `oz` values correspond to which color. `vmin` and `vmax` can change this mapping of colors.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

wd = [90, 297, 309, 336, 20, 2, 334, 327, 117, 125, 122, 97, 95, 97, 103, 106, 125, 148, 147, 140, 141, 145, 144, 151, 161]
ws = [15, 1.6, 1.8, 1.7, 2.1, 1.6, 2.1, 1.4, 3, 6.5, 7.1, 8.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.8, 10.2, 11.4, 9.7, 8.6, 7.1, 6.4, 5.5, 5, 5, 6]
oz = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 90, 140, 100, 106, 125, 148, 147, 140, 141, 145, 144, 151, 161]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "polar"})

cont = ax.tricontourf(np.radians(np.array(wd)), ws, oz, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar(cont)
plt.show()
```

[image: demo plot]

With `ax.scatter(np.radians(np.array(wd)), ws, c=oz, cmap='hot', vmax=250)` you could create a scatter plot to get an idea how the input looks like when colored.

You might want to incorporate Python's [windrose library](https://windrose.readthedocs.io/en/latest) to get polar plots to resemble a windrose.

Another approach, which might be closer to the one intended by the linked question, would be to use scipy's `interpolate.griddata` to map the data to a grid. To get rid of the areas without data, an 'under' color of 'none' can be used, provided that `vmin` is higher than zero.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

wd = [90, 297, 309, 336, 20, 2, 334, 327, 117, 125, 122, 97, 95, 97, 103, 106, 125, 148, 147, 140, 141, 145, 144, 151, 161]
ws = [15, 1.6, 1.8, 1.7, 2.1, 1.6, 2.1, 1.4, 3, 6.5, 7.1, 8.2, 10.2, 10.2, 10.8, 10.2, 11.4, 9.7, 8.6, 7.1, 6.4, 5.5, 5, 5, 6]
oz = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 90, 140, 100, 106, 125, 148, 147, 140, 141, 145, 144, 151, 161]
wd_rad = np.radians(np.array(wd))
oz = np.array(oz, dtype=np.float)


WD, WS = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 36), np.linspace(min(ws), max(ws), 16 ))
Z = interpolate.griddata((wd_rad, ws), oz, (WD, WS), method='linear')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "polar"})
cmap = plt.get_cmap('hot')
cmap.set_under('none')
img = ax.pcolormesh(WD, WS, Z, cmap=cmap, vmin=20)
plt.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: gridded plot]

Comment: If this answers your question, you might consider [marking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answer) it as accepted.