# Bivariate polar plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, openair

I've recently found this great R library (openair) that allows plot bivariate (pollutants-wind, for example) polar plots such as this one in which are represented pollutants concentrations in function of wind speed and direction:

[image: Bivariate polar plot]

This is the link to the R function with some examples:
https://davidcarslaw.github.io/openair/reference/polarPlot.html

Is there any way to do something like this in Python?

EDIT: This is exactly what I'm looking forward: A scatterplot or windrose with a third dimension for the temperature, the color, which doesn't depend at all of the position at the polar projection 
[image: Bivariate temperature-wind plot]

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071084/polar-contour-plot-in-matplotlib-best-modern-way-to-do-it) tackles something similar. If scatter plot suffices, check [this vignette](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html). You also might be interested in the [windrose library](https://github.com/python-windrose/windrose)

Comment: Mmm I'm sorry but I still don´t see it. I have a 3x341 data array (3 variables [Temp, wind_speed,wind_direction], 341 data of each variable). 
A windrose or a scatter plot would be great, but the issue is how to add a third dimension (the color) that isn't function of the wind speed values density but a function of the third variable, the temperature, that doesn't depend at all of the position at the polar projection.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702585/pollution-rose-plot-gridded) describes a situation with 3 variables: wind speed, wind direction and pollution. Instead of pollution you could create your 3rd variable as some function of temperature. I don't know of fully worked out solutions similar to Openair.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot @JohanC!!