# How to get rid of discontinuity on windrose pcolormap plot python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot a windrose with binned concentration values. Following the advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702585/pollution-rose-plot-gridded), and some modifications, I have created a plot. However, there is a discontinuity at around 0 deg. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
wd = list(merge_all_apr['Wind Dir (10s deg)'])
conc = list(merge_all_apr['Mean_CO2'])
ws = list(merge_all_apr['Wind Spd (km/h)'])

wd_rad = np.radians(np.array(wd))
conc = np.array(conc, dtype=np.float)

wind_speed = np.linspace(min(ws), max(ws), 16)

WD, WS = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 36), wind_speed)

print (WS)

Z = interpolate.griddata((wd_rad, ws), oz, (WD, WS), method='linear')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "polar"})
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
#cmap.set_under('none')
img = ax.pcolormesh(WD, WS, Z, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=40, alpha = 0.70)
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1) 
plt.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

And the result is:

[image: This image]

As a scatter, it works fine and looks like

[image: This]

I'm not sure how to provide the data in a concise way, but any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also provide values for `wd_rad` just lower than `0` and larger than `2*pi` using `np.where`, adding `2*pi` for small values and subtracting `2*pi` for large values. `np.tile(ws, 2)` and `np.tile(conc, 2)` then associate the extended version of `wd_rad` with the same concentration values. Using also these extended values in `interpolate.griddata` makes sure the concentration values wrap around at `0` and `2*pi`.

As an aside, note that 'jet' is a colormap that looks nice, but is [very misleading](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/) as it creates yellow highlights at the wrong spots. (Also, converting pandas columns to lists is quite slow and memory consuming, better leave them in their numpy array format.)

The code below supposes that `oz` in the question is the same array as `conc`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

# wd = merge_all_apr['Wind Dir (10s deg)']
# conc = merge_all_apr['Mean_CO2']
# ws = merge_all_apr['Wind Spd (km/h)']

N = 100
wd = np.random.uniform(0, 360, N)
conc = np.random.uniform(0, 40, N)
ws = np.random.uniform(0, 45, N)

wd_rad = np.radians(np.array(wd))
conc = np.array(conc, dtype=np.float)

wd_rad_ext = np.where(wd_rad < np.pi, wd_rad + 2 * np.pi, wd_rad - 2 * np.pi)

wind_speed = np.linspace(min(ws), max(ws), 16)

WD, WS = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 37), wind_speed)

Z = interpolate.griddata((np.hstack([wd_rad, wd_rad_ext]), np.tile(ws, 2)), np.tile(conc, 2),
                         (WD, WS), method='linear', rescale=True)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4), subplot_kw={"projection": "polar"})
cmap = plt.get_cmap('magma')
for ax in axes:
    if ax == axes[0]:
        img = ax.pcolormesh(WD, WS, Z, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=40)
    else:
        img = ax.scatter(wd_rad, ws, c=conc, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=40)
    ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    plt.colorbar(img, ax=ax, pad=0.12)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

If you don't want an interpolation, but want to draw segments of 10 degrees wide to represent each area, [`plt.hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) can be employed.

Special parameters to `hist2d`:

- `bins=(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 37), np.linspace(min(ws), max(ws), 17))`: the wind directions will be divided into 36 regions (37 boundaries); the speeds will be divided into 16 regions
- `weights=conc`: instead of a usual histogram that counts the number of values into each little region, use the concentrations; when multiple concentrations are measured in the same little region, they are averaged
- `cmin=0.001`: leave regions blank when their concentration value is less than `0.001`
- `cmap = 'magma_r'`: use the reversed 'magma' colormap, so the high values get dark and the low get light colors (see [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) about other colormaps that might be more suitable to illustrate the data, but try not to use 'jet')

The return values of `hist2d` are a matrix of histogram values, the bin boundaries (x and y) and a collection of colored patches (which can be used as input for the colormap).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

N = 100
wd = np.random.uniform(0, 360, N)
conc = np.random.uniform(0, 40, N)
ws = np.random.uniform(0, 45, N)

wd_rad = np.radians(np.array(wd))
conc = np.array(conc, dtype=np.float)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4), subplot_kw={"projection": "polar"})
cmap = 'magma_r'
for ax in axes:
    if ax == axes[0]:
        _, _, _, img = ax.hist2d(wd_rad, ws, bins=(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 37), np.linspace(min(ws), max(ws), 17)),
                                 weights=conc, cmin=0.001, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=40)
    else:
        img = ax.scatter(wd_rad, ws, c=conc, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=40)
    ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    plt.colorbar(img, ax=ax, pad=0.12)
plt.show()
```

[image: hist2d plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That fixed the problem for the most part! I was just wondering if you knew a way to ensure that it doesn't plot colour where there is missing data? (For ex, on your plot, at 225 deg and 40km/h ws, it shows to be quite a high concentration whereas on the other plot there is no data) I understand this may be a limit of using the linear interpolation, but if there's  a more physical method (eg with binning somehow?) that may be better? - I checked out the windrose documentation, and couldn't find something to fit this case well, unfortunately

Comment: Is the 2d histogram closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes!! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!