# How to create a 2x2 array from (lat, long, value) list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I've got a pandas DataFrame containing `lat`, `lon`, `val`.

```
lat  lon  val
50   60   1
51   60   2
52   60   3
50   61   7
51   61   8
52   61   9
```

To use [matlibplot.contourf](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html), I have to send grid data, instead of vectors.

To this, I use [numpy.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), to generate

```
lat = [50, 51, 52, 50, 51, 52]
lon = [60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 61]
x, y = np.meshgrid(lat, lon)

lat = 50 51 52 50 51 52
      50 51 52 50 51 52
      50 51 52 50 51 52
      50 51 52 50 51 52
      50 51 52 50 51 52
      50 51 52 50 51 52

lon = 60 60 60 60 60 60
      60 60 60 60 60 60
      60 60 60 60 60 60
      61 61 61 61 61 61
      61 61 61 61 61 61
      61 61 61 61 61 61
```

Now, I need to create the `val` as:

```
val = 1 2 3 1 2 3 
      1 2 3 1 2 3
      1 2 3 1 2 3
      7 8 9 7 8 9
      7 8 9 7 8 9
      7 8 9 7 8 9
```

But I have no ideia how to do that "the proper way".

Of course, I can create an empty 3x3 array len(lat x lon), iterate over their keys, and populate the values. But it seems to be the wrong way to do it.

Also, there is the [DataFrame.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap), so I don't get my "hands dirty" making the iteration, but it also feels wrong (and slow).

How can I create the `val` array?

Comment: how would this look with more than 4 rows?

Comment: Post your meshgrid approach, there is probably a way to create it all in one go.

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a 2 by 3 grid:

```
lat = [50, 51, 52, 50, 51, 52]
lon = [60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 61]
val = [1,2,3,7,8,9]

x = np.array(lat).reshape(2,3)
y = np.array(lon).reshape(2,3)
z = np.array(val).reshape(2,3)

plt.contourf(x,y,z)
```

More information in the dupe: [Make contour of scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764814/make-contour-of-scatter)