# creating 2d array from single arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, grid

I have observation data from a satellite called Aeolus. The data are single arrays. So one 1D array for date and time, one for latitude information, one for longitude information and one for wind speed.

```
date_aeolus
lat_aeolus
lon_aeolus
wind_aeolus
```

In the end I would like to create a pcolormesh lat - lon plot of the wind speed. But therefore I need the wind speed as 2D:

```
wind_aeolus[lat,lon]
```

How can I create such an array?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like `zip` function, you can use it as follows: `zip(lat_aeolus,lon_aeolus)`

Comment: In the general case, you may need to use interpolation. But possibly, your arrays have a certain structure, which would allow for reshaping. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407498/4124317).

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to just make a 2D array, a couple `for` loops should work fine.

```
lat = ['1', '2', '3']
lon = ['2', '3', '4']

Array = []

for i in range(0, len(lat)) :
    Array.append([lat[i]])

for i in range(0, len(Array)) :
    Array[i].append(lon[i])
```

The `zip()` function also works well in this situation, like @user2977071 said.

```
zip(lat, lon)
```