# How to specify the z values in a contour plot - seaborn / matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn

I am measuring the accuracy of a machine learning classifier which has two parameters. I would like to have the x and y axes represent these two parameters, and have the z index (the contour / depth) show the accuracy of the model.

The problem i'm having is that seaborn's `kdeplot` seems to be calculating the z index based on where the points are in the graph; It doesn't show the accuracy, but rather the concentration of points.

Is there a way to use the accuracy (the score of these points) to show the depth of the graph?

Or maybe this isn't the best way to represent this kind of information?

```py
sns.jointplot(x="n_estimators", y="learning_rate", 
              data=data, height=8, ratio=10, space=0, 
              color="#383C65")\
    .plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, zorder=0, shade=True, shade_lowest=False,
                cmap=sns.cubehelix_palette(light=1, as_cmap=True), legend=True, cbar=False,
                cbar_kws={})
```

Where `data` is a pandas Dataframe with three columns: `learning_rate`, `n_estimators`, `accuracy`

I have also used matplotlib's contourf to the same results. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image: KDE plot]

Comment: seaborn jointplot (or distplot for that matter) plots the density of points. If you want a contour plot, use matplotlib's `contourf` function.

Comment: Thanks. But `contourf`'s documentation says Z should be `array-like(N, M)` and i only have a 1D array. How do i go about converting it into this shape? The documentation is a bit sparse

Comment: In that case either interpolate on a grid, or use `tricontourf`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407498/4124317).