# Heatmap in Python using matplotlib from 3 independent arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

I would like to do a heatmap plot using three independent vectors x, y and z. I have looked at examples over the internet and most of them show how to do heatmap plot for x, y and z represented as a 2D matrix

So, can someone please help me on how can I convert 3 independent vectors to a 2d matrix, which I can eventually use for doing heatmap plots

One thing that I thought was to create matrix by first discretizing and arranging in ascending order x and y, and finding z at the new "x" and "y" combinations. But, there could be cases in which "z" cannot be computed due to lack of data during interpolation

I am bit confused, and I would like to seek help in this regard

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764814/make-contour-of-scatter/43407498#43407498

Comment: I’m voting to close this, it’s far too broad and vague. OP, you probably need a guide/tutorial, or the documentation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Thanks for the link. I took some valuable stuff from it. I have now managed to create an interpolated matrix "z" as a function of "x" and "y" using griddata, and meshgrid. The contour plot works fine, but I still have to do the heatmap

Now, i tried to use the seaborn package. The command was quite simple sns.heatmap(yourmatrix). But the problem is that the heatmap created comes has index from 1 to n (where n is the number of elements) on the axis instead of "x" and "y" values. Due to this the heatmap does not make sense. Any workarounds ?

Comment: Do not use seaborn. matplotlib's `imshow` or `pcolormesh` are fine.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Thanks a lot for the tip. I tried the pcolormesh, like this - plt.pcolormesh(zi). But do you know how can I enter information about "x" and "y", because without it the heatmap would not make any sense as it is plotted against axes which are numericals from 1 until the maximum number of values in "x" and "y"

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Ok, nice it happened. I just entered plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi). Looks like my initial requirements are satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html#matplotlib-pyplot-pcolormesh). It does what you need: create a heat map of data that do not lie on a regular grid. You can specify how the data are interpolated (and extrapolated).

From the docs:

> `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh(*args, alpha=None, norm=None, cmap=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, shading='flat', antialiased=False, data=None, **kwargs)`
>
> Create a pseudocolor plot with a non-regular rectangular grid.
>
> Call signature:
>
> `pcolor([X, Y,] C, **kwargs)`
>
> X and Y can be used to specify the corners of the quadrilaterals.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you group memebers. With your help, I have been able to reach closer to the solution. The thing that I did was

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = mdf_merged.get('VariableX').samples
y = mdf_merged.get('VariableY').samples
z = mdf_merged.get('VariableZ').samples
###
xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),10)
yi = np.linspace(min(y),max(y),20)
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear')
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi)
```

Comment: The point of `pcolormesh` is that it can deal with non-gridded data. If you are interpolating anyway, use `imshow`.