# Plot 3D contourf based on given 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a `(2640, 96, 17)` array. I am able to plot it by scatter plot but I would like to see the whole shape of this array, so I think the surface plot or contour will be better. But I cannot deal with `z must be 2D array`. `z.ndim` shows 2. I don't know what is going on. Or anyone could provide a new method for me, I will be highly appreciated.

```
x = np.arange(Outfinal_add.shape[0])[:, None, None]
y = np.arange(Outfinal_add.shape[1])[None, 30:60, None]
x, y= np.broadcast_arrays(x, y)
Z = np.zeros((Outfinal_add.shape[1],Outfinal_add.shape[2]))
Z = Outfinal_add[1][:]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.contourf(x.ravel(),
           y.ravel(),
           Z.ravel())
```

`Outfinal_add` is the original data array `(2640,96,17)`.

Comment: Can you provide dummy data or `Outfinal_add` to replicate the results.

Comment: Does [this answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764960/565489) ?

Comment: @Asmus I think that answer has the initial that x,y,z are 1D array. That is the part I am stuck with. The thing I only have is a 3_D array which is extracted from .mat file. I don't know how to change it into 1D array.

Comment: @Furqan Hashim I tried np.random.rand(3,3,5). '''dummy = np.random.rand(3,3,5) // X1 = np.arange(dummy.shape[0])[:, None, None]//
Y1 = np.arange(dummy.shape[1])[None, :, None]//
X,Y= np.broadcast_arrays(X1, Y1) // Z = np.zeros((dummy.shape[1],dummy.shape[2]))//
Z = dummy[1][:]//
fig = plt.figure()//
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')//
ax.contourf(x.ravel(),
           y.ravel(),
           Z.ravel())'''

Comment: How do you expect to plot a 3D array in 3D?